# SAP Spartacus OccStoreFinderAdapter override

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Is there any way to override `OccStoreFinderAdapter` class in SAP Spartacus v3.x+? What I have already tried is to add a custom provider in `store-finder-feature.module.ts` like this

```
{
  provide: OccStoreFinderAdapter,
  useClass: CustomOccStoreFinderAdapter
}
```

but it still uses the OOTB one.

Comment: please try this:

{
  provide: StoreFinderAdapter,
  useClass: CustomOccStoreFinderAdapter
}

Comment: It does not work this way also

Answer (score 3):

### 2023-05-15 Update

Please mind to provide your custom `StoreFinderAdapter` *not in the `app.module` (not in the root injector*), but provide it in your lazy-loaded custom "wrapper" module of the storefinder feature.

For more, see docs of [Customizing Lazy Loaded Modules](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_COMPOSABLE_STOREFRONT/eaef8c61b6d9477daf75bff9ac1b7eb4/6ae18e81bc8542b8885bb10bb046d5c8.html#loio4e2b7f1115684e579d64b85b0adadd52).

It's needed, since the store finder feature became **lazy loaded** by default in new versions of Spartacus.

### 2021-06-09 Original answer

#### Solution

```js
{ 
   provide: StoreFinderAdapter,   // not OccStoreFinderAdapter
   useClass: ThmOccStoreFinderAdapter
}
```

#### Explanation

For the token `StoreFinderAdapter`, Spartacus OOTB passes the `OccStoreFinderAdapter` via `useClass` (but not via `useExisting`):

```js
{ 
   provide: StoreFinderAdapter,
   useClass: OccStoreFinderAdapter
}
```

Therefore `OccStoreFinderAdapter` is not an injectable and cannot be custom-provided. It was just used as a raw implementation of the abstract `StoreFinderAdapter`

---

**Note**: If `StoreFinderAdapter` was provided with `OccStoreFinderAdapter`  via `useExisting` and the `OccStoreFinderAdapter` was provided itself as an injectable (i.e. in the root injector: `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})`), then your code would work as you expected:

```js
{ 
   provide: OccStoreFinderAdapter,
   useClass: ThmOccStoreFinderAdapter
}
```

Comment: I tried it however my custom adapter is still not called. I provided this config in `store-finder-feature.module.ts`

Comment: @PiotrDziwoki - Were you able to succeed with this? I am also trying to extend an adapter which seems not possible.

Comment: Hi @PiotrDziwoki and Raj Pawan Gumdal. I've updated my original answer above. Please let me know if it works for you or if you have any questions.